# Retrieve subpage of a define subpage

Tags: mediawiki

I've a page with subpages, it looks like this (just an example, not my real data) :

```
-page
  ↳ apple
    ↳ iPhone
    ↳ iPad
  ↳ samsung
    ↳ Galaxy
```

I want to retrieve on the root page all the subpages of `apple`. I find a way to retrieve all subpages `{{Special:PrefixIndex/{{FULLPAGENAME}}/ |hideredirects=1 |stripprefix=1}}` but not a way to retrieve all in apple.

The expected response should be

```
• Iphone
• Ipad
```

Comment: Not sure if that can work, but did you simply try something like:
`{{Special:PrefixIndex/{{FULLPAGENAME}}/apple/ |hideredirects=1 |stripprefix=1}}` ???

Comment: @Florian, ok, it was as easy as that. Thanks :)

Comment: Awesome :D I've added the comment as an answer now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Special page `Special:Prefixtext` allows any level of prefixes, so it should be as easy as:
`{{Special:PrefixIndex/{{FULLPAGENAME}}/apple/ |hideredirects=1 |stripprefix=1}}`

(note the part, where `/apple/` is appended as a subpage to the fullpagename variable)